# How to call a jquery from vb codebehind (asp)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am new to jqueries and I have a problem calling a dialog box If ever my user has an invalid search query and did not put a starting date. See I have this jquery code

```
$(function(){          
  $("#dialog").dialog(function() {                                    
     $("#dialog").dialog()};
  });
});
```

Now I have these codes in vb :

```
 Sub Subsearch()
    If txtfrom.Text <> "" And txtto.Text <> "" Then
        //some codes

    ElseIf txtfrom.Text <> "" And txtto.Text = Nothing Then
        //some codes

    ElseIf txtfrom.Text = Nothing And txtto.Text <> "" Then

        //call my JQuery 

    Else
        // some codes

    End If
End Sub
```

Now how do I do this?

Comment: try to wrap your jqery in a string and then print that string with the help of response.write for instance. Dim myJquery as string ="$(function(){$("#dialog").dialog(function() {"#dialog").dialog()};});                          });" make sure they are all in a same line and now do respose.write(myJquery)

Comment: How to do that? I'm really new at this sorry

Comment: Its ok but have you called `jquery` then `jquery-ui` then put this code and in this code you have one extra `}`.

Comment: Yes i have called the jquery and jquery-ui..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Update to VB.NET

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "blah", "myfunction();", True
```

If you're using a ScriptManager, use RegisterStartupScript(), use it this way:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "modalscript",
"$(function() { $('#dialog').dialog(); });", true);
```

Comment: Do i put this after the elseif ? it says "this" is not declared

Comment: How do I name my function? Or know its name

Comment: add something like myfunction() which is a name given to a function between your function{ as $(function myfunction()

Comment: I tried putting the first one but the ";" and "this" are underlined blue

Comment: Hi @coder.. I have tried this near to your code `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "error", "myfunction();", True)`  and it worked I alse added this `$('#dialog').dialog('open'); ` and `autoOpen:false;` It works already now my problem is it appears every page load.. but also appears when the validation is met

Comment: That you need to modify you IF Else statement according to your convinience

Comment: It worked already thanks @coder The second one worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dim myjquery as string="$(function(){ $('#dialog').dialog(function() {$('#dialog').dialog()} ;  }); });"
response.write(myjquery)
```

Let me know if it works or not

Comment: the "#" sign turns blue and then an error saying "End of statement expected" comes out

Answer (score -2):

you could use the JQuery to validate your input boxes, thereby not having to use the VB code to do it...

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/

Comment: jQuery validation is **not** a substitute for server-side validation.

Comment: You weren't talking about adding an 'extra layer' of validation. You wrote, "thereby not having to use VB code to do it." Client-side validation should be for user experience purposes **only** - not as a replacement for server-side validation. If you are only implementing client-side validation then I can bypass it completely simply by switching Javascript off. Then, I can post whatever values I want, which, depending on the scenario, could open the way to devastating attacks.